# How fast can the Hulk go?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

With all of Hulk's muscle and might, the focus is generally on how hard he can hit or how much he can lift.

Yet, I'd like to know how fast he can move. Whether running speed or flight speed when he's jumping a mile in a single bound. What's the angry green giant's top speed?

Comment: http://static2.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/3/31336/630877-hulk5b.jpg / http://static8.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/3/31336/612270-defenders_060_06.jpg / http://static1.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/3/31336/666556-speed_2.jpg / http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/3/31336/620195-dddddd.jpg / http://static7.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/3/31336/610327-thousandleap.jpg

Comment: And this; http://comicvine.gamespot.com/hulk/4005-2267/forums/current-hulk-is-fast-1516737/?page=1

Comment: He can *jump* at least 11.2Km/s (escape velocity); http://i.stack.imgur.com/czw0U.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Why are there so many moons?

Comment: @asawyer - No. It's a space station.

Comment: @Valorum No these - are those all extra moons or something? http://i.imgur.com/EJcUhvS.png

Comment: @asawyer - I understood. I was just joking. I think all of those are actually planets.  Because he's in spaaaaaace!

Answer (score 1):

In [Incredible Hulk Annual Vol 1 2000](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Annual_Vol_1_2000), a police officer clocked the Hulk's leaping speed (for that particular leap) at 473 MPH.

[image]

[image]

[image]